# entire <tr> disappears after .click function

Tags: jquery

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong with my code?

Please understand that I'm just a beginner learning jquery. I'm trying to make a Check List using a `<table>` where you can add and remove items, and when you click on the check box, a checkmark appears followed by a "done!" contained on another `<td>`. The check mark disappears once you  click on the check box again. you can see my fiddlehere: http://jsfiddle.net/linyingsinc/w6XxP/1/

I've initially set `.checked` as hidden so that `.toggleClass` can remove that class when clicked, thus revealing the check mark. It works fine initially, but when I added this bit of jquery:

```
$(this).toggle(function() {  
var itemDone = '<td class="complete">done!</td>';  
$(this).parent('tr').append(itemDone);  
});
```

...the entire `<tr>` containing `<td class="checkbox">` disappears completely after a second. I just want to be able to toggle the checkmark and the "done!" bit on and off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of the `toggle()` function was removed in the latest versions of jQuery, so the `toggle()` function you're using now toggles visiblity, and just hides or shows everything.

You'll have to create your own toggle function :

```
$(document).on('click','.checkbox',function() {
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('checked');
    if ($(this).parent('tr').find('.complete').length) {
        $(this).parent('tr').find('.complete').remove();
    }else{
        var itemDone = '<td class="complete">done!</td>';
        $(this).parent('tr').append(itemDone);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/linyingsinc/w6XxP/1/)

Comment: Oh joy! thank you! No wonder I couldn't get the thing to work.